# bootstrapSwitch not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, switch-statement

I'm using bootstrapSwitch but it isn't displayed properly.
It looks like that and its state can't be changed. I tried with the following code:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>
```

```js
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

[image: switch]

Where I am wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the bootstrap-switch.min.css and bootstrap-switch.min.js from this cdn: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-switch

Also include bootstrap.min.css and it just works perfectly fine.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>

$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/deg4ztf4/

Comment: Thanks, but I saw my mistake. I had some conditions if checkbox is disabled. :)

Comment: Happy to help! :) Can I know the exact mistake, so i dont get stuck into it in future.